# How to connect AWS instance to a VPN and still be able to access it?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to connect my AWS EC2 Linux server to a VPN via PPTP. The problem is if I do that I immediatelly lose connection to the server. And I won't be able to connect to it unless I restart. Is there a way for me to connect the server to VPN while still be able to access it through SSH?